# Display Newsletter POP UP when customer leave page issue

Tags: magento-1.9, popup

We will show `newsletter popup` when customers `leave the site` Instead of showing popup on `customers visit` the site:

- When customer is going to close the website?
- When customer is going to go to another website?

How to do this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the code which you have tried for your popup?

Answer (score 3):

This javascript 'onbeforeunload' event is used to detect browser close or changing website. You can use the event to display popup.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
return "Do you really want to close?";
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work, indeed it displays the natif alert with the natif message but not with what your return, and is not what he is looking for  ? HE WANT A NEWS LETTER POP UP !

Comment: I think this answer provides a starting point. The OP can use this and in place of return he can add his popup code. @Prince

Comment: i want display popup newletter, not message

Comment: @Jaimin Sutariya it answered you, he don't want to display a message and also this exemple doesn't work for me

Comment: The stay on the page message will appear but you can trigger to show the newsletter block  in this function before return statement. And the user can decide to close the window or stay on page by seeing your newsletter window.

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function () {
jQuery('#newsletter').toggle();
return true;
};

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jquery. Please refer the Mouseleave and Mouseout function and set the event in your `body` tag. `Popup block` code shoud be in your header.phtml

For Example :

```
$( "body" ).mouseout(function() {
  //call your popup block
});
```

> https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Hope it will usefull for you.